# Is it possible to send streaming data CAD FILE to another pc on network to be printed(milled) but mill is connected via usb to pc 2.?

Tags: networking, usb

I am in the dental industry and are trying for pc1 to send the designed CAD FILE over the network to pc2 that has a mill connected to it via usb to be milled. The Mill is installed and is seen as a printer on Pc 2 . Is it possible for pc1 to send data to the mill over the network thru pc2 via the usb.?

Comment: If its a 'printer' - can you 'share' the printer the 'usual' way?

Comment: That’s important information that should be in the question instead of a temporary comment

Comment: None of the mills I know of can directly deal with a CAD file - they are always translated into mill paths and further into commands by some software. Is such a software installed on PC 2 and is it remoteable?